# Can i run outlook add-on method in background process when load function call?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, outlook-addin

> This is my code
>   there is two method one is notify mail,it call when new mail comes in
>   outlook. And second method is mailProcessTrigger it perform some
>   change in  mail. i want to run  **mailProcessTrigger()** method
>   another
>   **thread** and it call every 5 minutes. I am unable to make that method to
>   multi-thread.

```
namespace PhishCOP
    {
        public partial class Phishing
        {
            Outlook.Application outlookApp;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder deleterFolder = null;
            Outlook.Items mailItems = null;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
            Outlook.Items items;
            string SchemaTransportHeader = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E";
            const string PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102";

    private void Phishing_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {
            outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            inboxFolder = outlookApp.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            deleterFolder = outlookApp.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk);
            mailItems = inboxFolder.Items;//.Restrict("[Unread]=true");
            mailItems.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", true);
            AddACategory();
            items = inboxFolder.Items;

            items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(CallFunction);

           }


        private void CallFunction(object data)
        {
           //move mail to another folder
        }

        private void mailProcessTrigger()
        {
        //mail process
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items in the Outlook Object Model cannot be used in background threads and will lead to instability in your add-in and could cause it and Outlook to crash.  You can only use Extended MAPI with C++ or Redemption to run multi-threaded Outlook solutions.